# Why is my image not showing in Processing (Using Python)

Tags: python, function, loops, processing

I've had multiple issues with this assignment, including a ton of errors. I am trying to generate a "grid" of a shape for an assignment using nested for loops. I finally got the code to run, but now no images are appearing.

Heres my code, I am having problems with the draw function.

```
def setup():
    size(400, 400) 
    background(255)  

def drawCat(x, y, s):
  pushMatrix()
  translate(x,y)
  scale(s)
  fill(210,125,45)
  ellipse(75,90, 100, 100)
  triangle(15,35,25,85,65,50)
  triangle(135,35,125,85,85,50)
  fill(0)
  rect(35,37, 80,10)
  fill(0)
  rect(50,7, 50,40)

  ellipse(45,80,20,20)
  ellipse(105,80,20,20)
  fill(255,192,203)
  triangle(75,90,65,105,85,105)
  popMatrix()

def draw():
    startx = 0
    starty = 0
    rows = 5
    scale = 400 / rows
    for i in range(0,rows):
      for j in range(0,rows):
          drawCat(startx, starty, scale)
          startx += scale
    starty += scale
    startx = 0
```

This project has been a nightmare (Im in a college intro to programming course) and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So run through it on paper, yourself, instead of actually running it. `draw` gets called, rows is 5, scale is therefore 80, then you start looping. i is 0, j is 0, you drawCat(0,0,80). So we look in drawCat: you scaled the _entire sketch_ by a factor 80. A line from (2,2) to (2,3) is now going to get drawn at (160,160) running to (160,240). Now, your sketch is only 400x400. So... the odds that we'll _ever_ see anything are basically zero. Start by removing that translate and scale: do things draw? Cool, put one of them back in. Do things draw? Sweet, put the last one back. Fail? problem found.

Comment: This was extremely helpful - how should I scale it then? I was looking at it the wrong way but what I need is approx 1/n^2 of the canvas taken up. I was trying to fit the shape into sections of 80, not scale it by that.

Comment: That's not scaling, you want things _translated_ in steps 80 =) e.g you want to draw the same thing, just offset by i*80 in the x, and j*80 in the y direction. So you don't need `startx` or `starty` here. The `i` and `j` are enough: `drawCat(i*scale, j*scale)`, but you probably want to rename `scale` to `grid_size` instead, so that it reflects what it actually represents.

Comment: I want to make it fit within an imaginary "grid" so if there are less drawings they take up more space and if there are more it takes up less. So the size is inverse to the amount of drawings there are. I tried to make the scale 1/rows but i dont see anything on the canvas when I do that.

Comment: If you have a rectangular sketch with edges `width` (or `height` since they're the same), and you need an `n`x`n` grid, then each cell is `width/n` wide and high. So you got that math right, but you called it the wrong thing. That's just your `grid_size`. Now you need to know what size each cat is, so that you can scale based on `grid_size/cat_size`. If the cat size is only 40 and  your grid's 80, you want to scale by 2. If the cat's 120 and the grid is 80, you want to scale by 0.666 - also note that if _everything_ scales by the same factor, you don't need to push/pop that all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I'm struggling to figure out how I would calculate that. I've made the scale grid_size/150 (thats what ive determined to be the side of the cat with equal margins on both sides) but that makes the scale super tiny. Im pretty sure thats not the actual ratio - but I could use a hint as to how to proceed. Thank you so much again. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: I already told you how to implement it, but it _does_ require changing your cat related code to something that can report on its own width. You wrote the code that does the drawing, so you can write some more code that states how wide, and how high, an unscaled cat is.